# Which data sees a group of EntityManagers when one of them updates or saves changes?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-4, .net-4.0

I'm having the following doubt about contexts in entity framework:

Suppose that there are three contexts d1, d2 and d3. Every context has been instantiated at different moments in the application's execution flux (d3, after d2 and d2, after d1). If application logic modifies some entities managed by d2 and executes d2.SaveChanges() (or any operation implying an update or a create), changes are seen by d3 and d1 after d2.SaveChanges() execution?

Could you provide some bibliography supporting your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are seen only after you refresh them from date store. Changes in d2 don't affect other contexts. d1 and d3 contain data in state, that you retrieved from database, before changes made in d2. If you want up to date state, you have to refresh data in them yourself. If this was done automatically, it would be not very efficient. That is also why context's life should be short. If you hold it too long, it contains out of date entities.

Comment: Could you give me some bibliography or links?

Comment: So a context acts as if it were some kind of transaction?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738470.aspx - Every ObjectContext has ObjectStateManager, that holds local copies of entities retrieved from database. If you change entities in d1 context, ObjectStateManager in d2 doesn't change, it still holds the same values. Of course this happens only if d2 retrieved data modified by d1 before modification.